# How to add a long comment to a statement properly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, pep

I am trying to follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments) in my project.
E.g. there is some statement which should have a long comment (so line length more than 79 characters now):

```
    fields_to_display = ['id', 'order_item']  # set here a list of fields to display when something happens somewhere
```

In [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments) we read:

> An inline comment is a comment on the same line as a statement.

So i guess i should use an inline comment.
If so how should i make it fit the [`79 characters restriction`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19) properly?

Comment: 1) you can put it before the line as a [block comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments), 2) PEP8 is not a holy scripture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should try to make all lines fit within `79 chars` by just carefully putting specific keywords to explain it, rather than using a proper English sentence.

But, if you have to have a long description, you can break comments in multiple lines.

```
""" Multi-line comment used 
here for my code. """
```

Well `PEP-8` also says,

> Inline comments are unnecessary and in fact distracting if they state the obvious.

So, it's better to have [`docstrings`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/docstrings) under your method definition explaining the method, rather than putting it on each line. Something like this:

```
def greet(name):
    """
    This function greets to
    the person passed in as
    a parameter
    """
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!")
```

Comment: docstrings aren't useful for comments about small number of lines of code.

Comment: @martineau Agreed. Please don't go on the example I pasted in my answer. This was just to let OP know that docstrings are also an option. And they can be rather useful in something like defining a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just try breaking the comments into multiple lines. This way you could  work around the actual `79 chars` rule.